# Configuring Remote MYSQL with a Dynamic IP

Tags: python, networking, cpanel

I am connecting my python software to a remote msql server.

i have had to add an access host on cPanel just for my computer but the problem is the access host, which is my IP, is dynamic.

How can i connect to the remote server without having to change the access host everytime?

thanks guys, networking is my weakness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is probably to find a [dynamic DNS] provider. The idea is to have a client running on your machine which updates a DNS entry on a remote server. Then you can use the hostname provided instead of your IP address in cPanel.

Comment: I assume you mean DMZ. This is quite different. DMZ (demilitarized zone) is a way of deactivating the firewall on your router and forwarding all incoming connections to a particular machine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bash script for linux which can be run to check continuously whether the IP has changed and update the providers record if necessary. It is for cPanel and requires editing the code to insert the credentials, which is trivial.

Download from [github](https://github.com/CpanelInc/cpanel-dynamicdns-tools)